# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime - Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

Been having a ton of issues loading Tensorflow. I've uninstalled and reinstalled numpy (now it's up to date, that was another initial error), uninstalled and reinstalled Tensorflow, and uninstalled and reinstalled Nextgenrnn (the package I plan to use it in combination with).

Launching python and calling "import tensorflow", I receive this really long error message.

Here is a full stack trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have Python 3.5.6 installed from Anaconda, running on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This is an issue with the version of a TensorFlow binary. The error `Symbol not found: _clock_gettime` says that the import was expecting to find that function in the .so and could not find it. That is what happens when a new function is added to the .so, that the import expects to find, but the .so is an earlier version that doesn't contain it.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you – so I need to update my other packages? or just use an older tensorflow?

Comment: The original error seems to be complaining about /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib but I have no idea what that does.

Comment: @BoarGules `libSystem` is a huge wrapper library on macOS that wraps nearly every library that macOS ships with including libc which is is where `clock_gettime` is located. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the macOS SDK `clock_gettime` is declared like this: `__CLOCK_AVAILABILITY
int clock_gettime(clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp);`

and if we look at the definition of the `__CLOCK_AVAILABILITY` macro: `#define __CLOCK_AVAILABILITY __OSX_AVAILABLE(10.12) __IOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0)`

We can see that `clock_gettime` was not added to the API until macOS 10.12. You are on El Capitan which is macOS 10.11. You need to update your OS, or downgrade your packages.